# Constraint length in a convolutional code

Tags: definition, information-theory, coding-theory

Regarding convolutional error correcting code with $k=1$ (single input), I'm puzzled with different definitions for the *constraint length*.

- In some books [4, 5], the constraint length is defined as the number of shift-registers.
- But in [1, 2, 3], the constraint length is defined as the number of shift-registers plus one.

What about this difference in definition? What can I follow?

### References:

[1] Page 231 of the book "Andrew J. Viterbi, Jim K. Omura - Principles of Digital Communication and Coding"

[2] https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/poly2trellis.html

[3] https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-02-introduction-to-eecs-ii-digital-communication-systems-fall-2012/readings/MIT6_02F12_chap07.pdf

[4] Page 459 of the book "Shu Lin, Daniel Costello - Error Control Coding - 2nd edition"

[5] Page 272 of the book "Richard E. Blahut - Algebraic codes for data transmission"

Comment: There are varying conventions. You can stick to one you are comfortable with. Do explain your choice to your audience.

Answer (score -1):

Each message bit influence a span of n(m+1) successive output bit the quantity n(m+1) is called as constraint length

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your post and add some more information to your answer. It would be particularly useful if you can also answer directly to the initial question.